# Change line spacing in winform RichTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, richtextbox

I'm using in my winform project a RichTextBox control to display a kind of old console screen. 
This works perfectly but there is a space between the lines.
Is it possible to change this space to be 0 or anything near that.
If i paint a line from vetical line from line 1 to line 5 i don't want any spacing between the line.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Look at this link for some sample code for Josh's answer: http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/how-to-increase-space-between-rows-of-text-in-richtextbox-37805.shtml

Comment: For those who want working code to set line spacing in a richtextbox see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526911/winform-richtextbox-deep-line-spacing-and-character-spacing?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually a lot that the Windows Forms RichTextBox doesn't expose. If you have the HWND (Handle property) to the control, you can use the SendMessage API to send the EM_SETPARAFORMAT message to play with the formatting.

In particular the [PARAFORMAT2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787942.aspx) structure does have some line spacing options that may be relevant. You will have to get your hands dirty with interop though.

Comment: Could you please put a sample here? because i could not open Hans Olson link