# WinForm richtextbox deep line spacing and character spacing

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How to edit line spacing and character spacing on richtextbox in winform? I've tried PARAFORMAT2 but it does not allow deep setting. I want to set spacing like photoshop. For example;

[image: Spacing Example]

In the picture is three different spacing format. How to set spacing like 1,2,3 in the picture?

Comment: Do you mean Line Spacing or Character Spacing?

Comment: yes, i mean both of them but firstly line spacing is necessary.

Comment: You can perform Line Spacing using `PARAFORMAT2` . What's the problem?

Comment: I want to make very smaller line spacing. I used PARAFORMAT2, it stretchs line spacing no problem. When I want to make very smaller spacing it getting smaller, smaller, smaller but after a certain value it does not getting smaller more. Fore example, Do not compress enough spacing lines.

Comment: @ATES When you are creating a new line only use `\n` and not `\n\r` this will solve your issue

Answer (score 5):

**Line Spacing**

You can send [`EM_SETPARAFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774276(v=vs.85).aspx) message to the rich text box control and pass [`PARAFORMAT2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787942(v=vs.85).aspx) as `lparam`. To control line spacing, you should set the `PFM_LINESPACING` flag in the `dwMask` member and set `bLineSpacingRule` and `dyLineSpacing` members of `PARAFORMAT2` to suitable values based on your requirements.

Since you need fine-tuning for line spacing, it seems 4 is suitable for `bLineSpacingRule` and then you can set `dyLineSpacing` to any value in twip unit. For more information about available options for `bLineSpacingRule`, read [`PARAFORMAT2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787942(v=vs.85).aspx) documentations.

```
public void SetSelectionLineSpacing(byte bLineSpacingRule, int dyLineSpacing)
{
    PARAFORMAT2 format = new PARAFORMAT2();
    format.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(format);
    format.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
    format.dyLineSpacing = dyLineSpacing;
    format.bLineSpacingRule = bLineSpacingRule;
    SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref format);
}
```

**Character Spacing**

Based on documentation of `sSpacing` in [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883(v=vs.85).aspx), setting character spacing has no effect on the text displayed by a rich edit control.

**Code**

```
public class ExRichText : RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, 
                                             Int32 wParam, ref PARAFORMAT2 lParam);

    private const int SCF_SELECTION = 1;
    public const int PFM_LINESPACING = 256;
    public const int EM_SETPARAFORMAT = 1095;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct PARAFORMAT2
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public uint dwMask;
        public Int16 wNumbering;
        public Int16 wReserved;
        public int dxStartIndent;
        public int dxRightIndent;
        public int dxOffset;
        public Int16 wAlignment;
        public Int16 cTabCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public int[] rgxTabs;
        public int dySpaceBefore;
        public int dySpaceAfter;
        public int dyLineSpacing;
        public Int16 sStyle;
        public byte bLineSpacingRule;
        public byte bOutlineLevel;
        public Int16 wShadingWeight;
        public Int16 wShadingStyle;
        public Int16 wNumberingStart;
        public Int16 wNumberingStyle;
        public Int16 wNumberingTab;
        public Int16 wBorderSpace;
        public Int16 wBorderWidth;
        public Int16 wBorders;
    }

    public void SetSelectionLineSpacing(byte bLineSpacingRule, int dyLineSpacing)
    {
        PARAFORMAT2 format = new PARAFORMAT2();
        format.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(format);
        format.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
        format.dyLineSpacing = dyLineSpacing;
        format.bLineSpacingRule = bLineSpacingRule;
        SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your post. I tired your code but there is a small problem. Line spacing never be zeroand under. When `dyLineSpacing` falls below the 420 value, characters looking faded seem cuts. 

First try (No problem);
`exRichText1.SetSelectionLineSpacing(4, 420);`
first trying screen: (http://prntscr.com/a6a6un)

Second try (faulty);
`exRichText1.SetSelectionLineSpacing(4, 220);`
second trying screen: (http://prntscr.com/a6a85j)

Comment: Your second screenshot is an expected result. To see how the spacing works decrease or increase dyLineSpacing from the initial value (420 in your sample code) by 10 each time you click on a decrease/increase button.

Comment: I know, well how to solve the problem this, in second secreenshot?