# Richtextbox DetectUrl bug

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

When I enable **DetectUrls** in **RichTextBox** and type some link, area on which I can click to open the link, not only over the link, but also on the entire area under it. Bug appears only if in **RichTextBox** one line of text. How to fix it?

**Video**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y518X.gif 
https://i.imgur.com/xnO1t8G.gifv

Comment: Did you changed LineHeight property?

Comment: @FarhadMehrad I did not change any properties

Comment: so change this property.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad **RichTextBox** does not have such property
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8#properties

Comment: My bad. you're right, LineHeight is a property in WPF. look at this it might help. [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/richtextbox-in-C-Sharp/) and this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526911/winform-richtextbox-deep-line-spacing-and-character-spacing)

Comment: @FarhadMehrad Thanks, but the problem only with links. If there is no new line under the link, the click area extends to the entire area under the link. Change line height does not help.

Comment: Edit your question and add the designer.cs of your form, maybe we can find the solution.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad lol, its weird, but this bug appear only in old versions of **.Net Framework**, when I change version to **4.7.1** // **4.7.2** this bug is disappeared