# RichTextBox line spacing in Windows Form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I am looking at changing the spacing between lines in `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099692/change-line-spacing-in-winform-richtextbox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526911/winform-richtextbox-deep-line-spacing-and-character-spacing) SO articles and came to the conclusion I need to play around with [PARAFORMAT2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/desktop/api/richedit/ns-richedit-paraformat2) structure.

My requirement is that I need to be setting the line spacing to one half line spacing. Which means I need to be using `bLineSpacingRule = 4` and then `dyLineSpacing = 100` (on my system single line spacing looks like 200)

But on doing this the text gets chopped in half. What I need to for the "Space to be nearly half a line" without loosing half my line

[image: Results]

- The first square is with`bLineSpacingRule = 4` and `dyLineSpacing = 100`
- The second square is with`bLineSpacingRule = 4` and `dyLineSpacing = 200`
- I need the 3rd Square.

How do I achieve this?

My control is declared as follows

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    string[] Cards = { "A", "K", "Q", "J", "T", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2" };
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

    public class ReadOnlyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
                                         Int32 wParam, ref PARAFORMAT2 lParam);

        private const int SCF_SELECTION = 1;
        public const int PFM_LINESPACING = 256;
        public const int EM_SETPARAFORMAT = 1095;
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct PARAFORMAT2
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public uint dwMask;
            public Int16 wNumbering;
            public Int16 wReserved;
            public int dxStartIndent;
            public int dxRightIndent;
            public int dxOffset;
            public Int16 wAlignment;
            public Int16 cTabCount;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
            public int[] rgxTabs;
            public int dySpaceBefore;
            public int dySpaceAfter;
            public int dyLineSpacing;
            public Int16 sStyle;
            public byte bLineSpacingRule;
            public byte bOutlineLevel;
            public Int16 wShadingWeight;
            public Int16 wShadingStyle;
            public Int16 wNumberingStart;
            public Int16 wNumberingStyle;
            public Int16 wNumberingTab;
            public Int16 wBorderSpace;
            public Int16 wBorderWidth;
            public Int16 wBorders;
        }

        public void SetSelectionLineSpacing(byte bLineSpacingRule, int dyLineSpacing)
        {
            PARAFORMAT2 format = new PARAFORMAT2();
            format.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(format);
            format.dwMask = PFM_LINESPACING;
            format.dyLineSpacing = dyLineSpacing;
            format.bLineSpacingRule = bLineSpacingRule;
            SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, ref format);
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
        const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
        const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool SelectionHighlightEnabled { get; set; }
        public ReadOnlyRichTextBox()
        {
            ReadOnly = true;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            ContextMenu = null;
            BackColor = Color.White;
            GotFocus += TextBoxGotFocus;
            Cursor = Cursors.Arrow; // mouse cursor like in other controls
            SelectionHighlightEnabled = false;
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS && !SelectionHighlightEnabled)
                m.Msg = WM_KILLFOCUS;

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            HideCaret(this.Handle);
        }
    }
    private ReadOnlyRichTextBox[] r = new ReadOnlyRichTextBox[169];
    public MainForm()
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        //InitializeComponent();
        //splitContainer1.TabStop = false;
        //RichTextBox rr = new RichTextBox();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 169; i++)
        {
            r[i] = new ReadOnlyRichTextBox();
            r[i].SetSelectionLineSpacing(4,200); // This function is called to set line spacing
            //tabControl2.TabPages["Range"].Controls.Add(r[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(r[i]);
            r[i].Size = new Size(40, 40);
            r[i].Location = new Point(x, y);

            if (i % 13 == 12)
            {
                x = 0;
                y += 40;
            }
            else
            {
                x += 40;
            }
            int a = i / 13;
            int b = i % 13;
            string temp = ((a < b) ? (Cards[a] + Cards[b]) : (Cards[b] + Cards[a]));
            r[i].Text += temp + ((a < b) ? "s" : ((a > b) ? "o" : " "));
            if (a == b)
                r[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128 + 5 * a, 128 + 5 * a, 255);
            else if (a < b)
                r[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128 + 5 * a, 255, 128 + 5 * a);
            else if (a > b)
                r[i].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128 + 5 * a, 128 + 5 * a);

           
            r[i].Text = r[i].Text + "\n\r" + a.ToString() + b.ToString();
            r[i].SelectionStart = 0;
            r[i].SelectionLength = 3;
            r[i].SelectionFont = new Font(r[i].Font.FontFamily, (float)8.0);
            r[i].SelectionStart = 3;
            r[i].SelectionLength = r[i].TextLength - 3;

            r[i].SelectionFont = new Font(r[i].Font.FontFamily, (float)7.2);
        }
    }        
    private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        HideCaret(Handle);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

I am restricted to `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` and cannot use `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` as this is not a WPF application.

Comment: Duty check: where you unable to do this with [Margins and Paddings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/margin-and-padding-in-windows-forms-controls)?

Comment: @BennettYeo my understanding is that margin and paddings effect the space between the text and the borderof the control.. how can I reduce the space between lines by playing around with these 2 parama?

Comment: @HansPassant please elaborate? why do need the use EM_GETPARAMFORMAT ? I already have set the params I need? and why increment? why not just jump to the value i need? considering i need to reduce the default value from single line to 0.5 line in what step do I decrement the values?

Comment: I found the issue.
This has nothing to do with line spacing and everything to do with how I create my new line. I was using `\n\r` for new line when `\n` was enough strangely this caused a 3rd line to come in between my 2 text lines which cased the illusion of  excessive line spacing

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your time this was not a winform issue it was a simple text formatting issue which created a phantom line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of \r\n or WriteLine, try using the SelectionIndent property
this works!

```cs
rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Multiline = true;

rtb.AppendText("Line1" + Environment.NewLine);
rtb.SelectionIndent = 36;
rtb.AppendText(new string('Line2', 250));
rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
rtb.SelectionIndent = 0;
rtb.AppendText("Line3");
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the RTF code directly. Replace 1600 by your line-spacing. But there is a minimum that you can't exceed.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Christ{
public class Dartagnan
{
static void Main()
{
    var form = new Form();
    var rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\sl1600\";
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    rtb.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    form.Controls.Add(rtb);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
}
}
```

Another solution is to use RichTextBox.SelectionCharOffset = 20, or your line-spacing.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Christ{
public class Dartagnan
{
static void Main()
{
    var form = new Form();
    var rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    rtb.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    rtb.SelectAll();
    rtb.SelectionCharOffset = 20;
    form.Controls.Add(rtb);
    form.ShowDialog();
}
}
}
```

Once again, there is a minimum that you can't exceed. I writed a string on the background to make a shadow effect, with two lines of text.